# LatLng(double.parse(prediction.lat), double.parse(prediction.long))) The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter

How do i solve this error in my flutter project

```
     Future<void> getLocationFromPlace(int index) async {
    if (autocompletePlaces.isNotEmpty) {
      locationController.text = autocompletePlaces[index].description!;
      searchAddressController.clear();
      final prediction =
          await _service.getPlaceDetail(autocompletePlaces[index], uuid);
      uuid = const Uuid().v4();
      updatePosition(
          LatLng(double.parse(prediction.lat), double.parse(prediction.long)));
      autocompletePlaces.clear();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by passing a `String?` variable into a `String` param without null check.

To bypass the error,  you can do this: `autocompletePlaces[index].description ?? ''` to make the variable a `String`

Comment: i dont know why it has failed to work can anyone help with the solution???

Comment: @GreenLoop can you share all your "suspicious functions" that takes `String` as parameter?

Comment: List<Prediction> autocompletePlaces = [];
  final String? _userCookie;
  bool isUpdating = false;